# Application is crashing when camera is opened and zoomed. This is hybrid app running in HWC. SUP is middle war

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, crash, hybrid-mobile-app

Our application is built as hybrid app and running in Hybrid Web Container. Middle ware is SUP.

On opening and zooming the camera and on click of 'Use Photo' application is crashing.

On checking the logs.. its showing '`didHideZoomBar`' exception..

```
hwc.getPicture(
        fail,
        imageCapture,
        { quality: 20, targetWidth: 300, targetHeight: 300,
            sourceType: hwc.PictureOption.SourceType.CAMERA,
          destinationType: hwc.PictureOption.DestinationType.IMAGE_URI
        }
    );
```

Please let me know what changes has to be done to fix this issue.

Comment: This issue is present in iPadmini version 8.x only. Its working fine in IOS 7.x

Comment: I've had this problem on 8.4, 9.0, and 9.2.  Seemed like they fixed the problem in 9.1, but then broke it again in 9.2.  Did you find any resolution?